# What is returned from a "await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sql, parameters)"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use this method to call a stored procedure.

```
var abc = await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sql, parameters)
```

I see plenty of information on how to return data using parameters and that works okay.  But I cannot find anything that tells me what is returned from the call?

Can someone tell me what will be put into abc and how can it be used?

Comment: it will return `Task<T>`

Comment: But can you explain. How can I use that or what can I do with it ?  Is there some value I can get out of that ?

Comment: you need yo show more code

Answer (score 1):

As per
[MSDN Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync Method (String, Object[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220055(v=vs.113).aspx)

it returns `Task<int>`. Here it is shown:

```
public Task<int> ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(
    string sql,
    params Object[] parameters
)
```

> Return Value
>   Type: `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Int32>`
>   A task that represents the asynchronous operation. The task result contains the result returned by the database after executing the command.

Now it depends on what you have in your sql query (sql param in your case). But for example, if you have a simple DELETE query like:

```
DELETE student WHERE papertype = 'science'
```

it will return the number of rows affected by the command. It's not a production level query so please ignore it's quality but you get the idea!